# Workbook_SheetChange second time run returns an error

Tags: excel, vba

I've an event `Workbook_SheetChange`, checking if target range intersect some range and running some macro.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Set TRange = Target
If Intersect(TRange, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("str1").Range(Cells(29, 15), Cells(42, 15))) Then Call CheckIDH(TRange)
Set Target = Nothing
End Sub
```

First time I change the sheet it works, runs `CheckIDH` macro.
Macro "`CheckIDH`" is checking the target value in dictionary and if yes, adds data in some range. This adding data runs again `Workbook_SheetChange` but second time it returns an error in a string

```
If Intersect(TRange, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("str1").Range(Cells(29, 15), Cells(42, 15))) Then Call CheckIDH(TRange)
```

for the range

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("str1").Range(Cells(29, 15), Cells(42, 15))
```

[image]

Seems as if the range doesn't exist.

Code in a module

```vb
Public count As Long
Public Dic As New Collection

Sub CheckIDH(ByVal TRange As Range)
If Dic.count = 0 Then
    Call Fill_Dic
    Sheets("ñòð1").Activate
End If
For Each x In TRange
    If Exists(CStr(x), Dic) = True Then Sheets("str1").Cells(x.Row, 1) = Dic(CStr(x)).Desc
    Sheets("ñòð1").Activate
    Set Target = Nothing
Next x
End Sub

Sub Fill_Dic()
Dim Tmp As String
Sheets("Dic").Activate
count = 0
Do While Cells(count + 1, 1) <> 0
    count = count + 1
    If count > 1 And Exists(CStr(Cells(count, 1)), Dic) = False Then
        Dic.Add Item:=New IDH, Key:=CStr(Cells(count, 1))
        Dic(CStr(Cells(count, 1))).IDHNbr = Cells(count, 1)
        Dic(CStr(Cells(count, 1))).Desc = Cells(count, 2)
    End If
Loop
End Sub

Function Exists(Key As String, Col As Collection) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Exists = TypeName(Col.Item(Key)) > ""
    Err.Clear
End Function
```

Comment: *This adding data runs again an event Workbook_SheetChange* is this correct? maybe you should deactivate events when calling `CheckIDH` and reactivate again after done.

Answer (score 1):

VBA is confused when/if you try intersecting ranges from different sheets...

Please, try the next updated event code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
   If sh.Name = "str1" Then
      If not Intersect(Target, sh.Range(sh.Cells(29, 15), sh.Cells(42, 15))) is nothing Then Call CheckIDH(Target)
   End if
End Sub
```

When the event was firstly fired, you were changing something in sheet "str1".

If it still behaves as you say, you should also show the `CheckIDH` code to see what and how it is exactly doing. Theoretically, if it changes something **in another sheet** the event is triggered again and without the new condition I placed, ranges from different sheets cannot be intersected and VBA raises an error. In the actual way, it shouldn't...

Comment: variant with `` Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
  ` If sh.Name = "str1" Then
      If Intersect(Target, sh.Range(Cells(29, 15), Cells(42, 15))) Then Call CheckIDH(Target)
   End if`    doesn't work

Comment: @IvanSTV What does "doesn't work" mean? Does it raise an error, doesn't it do anything? Or what? Please, check the updated code.

Comment: @ FaneDuru
The same error appears.

Comment: @IvanSTV Not sure that you refreshed the page (this one) and really tested the updated code. But not important now...

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

**(1)** You write

```
If Intersect(TRange, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("str1").Range(Cells(29, 15), Cells(42, 15))) Then Call CheckIDH(TRange)
```

`Intersect` is checking if two ranges have common cells. It returns the cells that are present in both ranges - and if those two ranges have no common cell (with other words `target` lays outside of `Range(Cells(29, 15), Cells(42, 15))` ) it will return `Nothing`

If `Target` lays *within* the range, your If basically will be `If Target Then`. VBA will check the *content* (=`Value`) of `Target` (the cell that was changed). Now you have several cases:

- If it is numeric and <> 0 (or `TRUE`), the Sub will be called.
- If it is 0 or `FALSE` or Empty, the Sub will not be called.
- If it is a String, you will get a type mismatch error (for the same reason you would get it for a statement like `If "ABC" Then`)
- If `Target` contains more than one cell (that's the case for example when the user uses Cut&Paste for more than one cell), you will also get a "type mismatch" error because you can't check more that one value at a time.

If, however, `Target` is not within your Range, you will check `If Nothing Then` and that gives you the runtime error 91 "object variable not set".

What you are missing is to check if the `Intersect` returned something. You do this with `If Not Intersect(...) Is Nothing Then`

**(2)** You can use `Intersect` only on Ranges of the same sheet. As your trigger is called for any change on any sheet, you need to ensure that you changed something on the sheet `Str1`, else you will get a runtime error 1004 "Method 'Intersect' failed. Either check the name of the sheet where the modification was done (check the name of `sh`) or move your code to the `Worksheet_Change` event of sheet "str1".

---

**TL,DR**
What you likely want to do is simply to check if the modified cell is within the range on a specific sheet. You do this for example like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If sh.Name <> "str1" Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target, sh.Range(Cells(29, 15), Cells(42, 15))) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Call CheckIDH(Target)
End Sub
```

Comment: Old A I know, but your code as posted will only work if sheet `str1` is active. Qualify the Cell's inside the Range